# Solenoidal forces

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, work, vector-fields

As far as I know a solenoidal vector field is such one that 
$$\vec\nabla\cdot \vec F=0.$$
However I saw a book on mechanics defining a solenoidal force as one for which the infinitesimal work identically vanish,
$$dW=\vec F\cdot d\vec r=0.$$
In this case, a solenoidal force would satisfy $\vec F\bot\vec v$, where $\vec v=\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$.
I could not find anywhere else people discussing a solenoidal force as in the latter case.

Are the two definitions equivalent? How so?

Comment: My vague guess is that the jargon makes sense because the magnetic field is solenoidal in the first sense ($\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$) and the magnetic _force_ is solenoidal in the second sense ($\vec{F} \propto \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$). So the tricky part is how the field and force correspond.

Comment: @knzhou, that was my first guess too. But unless it is equivalent to the usual definition of a solenoidal (vector field) force (which I couldn't see yet) it would be a rather "bad" jargon.

Comment: I'll second that; it just *is* bad jargon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counter example on equivalence may be the electric field created in a closed copper wire by a varying magnetic flux :

Such a field encloses on itself, i.e $$\vec\nabla.\vec E_M =0$$ However, it does make a work because it causes the electrons to move in the conductor and create a current, which means $$dW\not=0$$

Comment: Good point. That work in a closed loop would be just the electromotive force. It seems this counter example shows the two definitions are not equivalent.